# Login Authentication using ADO.NET in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, ado.net

This is my first here in Stackoverflow. So I just want to ask question about Login Authentication using ADO.NET in C#.

So here it goes.

I stumbled upon reading an eBook called "Syngress - SQL Injection Attacks and Defenses" and I was a bit confused with the example given on the book.

Here is the sample code from the book which I'm confuse with the examples

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string Sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=@username" + "AND password=@password";
cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
// Add parameters to SQL query
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",              // name
                   SqlDbType.NVarChar,       // data type
                   16);                      // length
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password",
                    SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                    16);
cmd.Parameters.Value["@username"] = username; // set parameters
cmd.Parameters.Value["@password"] = password; // to supplied values
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm confused with the "cmd.Parameters.Value" part because when try to code there is no Parameters.Value given in my IDE..

So what I did is i'm using cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashieruser", cashieruser); than Parameters.Value because its not found in the IntelliSense of Visual Studio 2010.

Here is my Code:

```
public bool isAuth(String cashieruser, String cashierpass)
{
    bool IsAuth = false;
    con.ConnectionString = conString;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cashieraccount WHERE cashieruser = ?cashieruser" + "AND cashierpass = ?cashierpass";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

    //Add parameters to SQL Query
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?cashieruser", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 35);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?cashierpass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashieruser", cashieruser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cashierpass", cashierpass);
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    try
    {
       con.Open();
       MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       if (rdr.Read())
       {   
          IsAuth = true;
       }
       else
          IsAuth = false;
    }
    finally
    {
       con.Close();
    }
    return IsAuth;
}
```

So I got an Exception: "Parameter '?cashieruser' has already been define."
So what Syntax will I use in order to set the parameters and supply the values?
*By the way, I'm using MySQL which it works with ADO.NET*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example there is an error. Parameters is the collection on which use the index.
The right syntax is:

```
cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = username; // set parameters 
cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = password; // to supplied values
```

In the second example you try to add the same parameters two times
You could combine create and value setting with just one line which allow to remove the AddWithValue lines

```
//Add parameters to SQL Query   
cmd.Parameters.Add("?cashieruser", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 35).Value = cashierUser;   
cmd.Parameters.Add("?cashierpass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = cashierPass;
```

Also the cmd.ExecuteScalar should be removed.
Run ExecuteReader after the connection open.
Finally, but this is probably a typo.
In your query text there is no space between the first where condition and the second part of the query. (really there is no need to concatenate string here.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly mention the variables in the query. Like this..

```
string sQuery = "select * from cashieraccount where cashieruser =" + cashieruser + " and cashierpass =" + cashierpass;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                //Login success code
            }
            else
            {
                //Login failed code
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?cashieruser", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 35);
```

will add the "?cashieruser" parameter to the Parameters collection of the cmd object.  Since the parameter is already added to the collection, you can set it's value like this:

```
cmd.Parameters["?cashieruser"].Value = cashieruser;
```

Alternatively, you can use the AddWithValue method if you haven't already added the parameter to the collection with the Add method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think the sample code you have should read:

```
cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = username; // set parameters
cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = password; // to supplied values
```

Secondly, you are getting that exception because you are trying to add the same parameter name twice. If you add your parameters using the `Add()` method and then use the syntax above to set the values that should sort your problem.